# Fatal error: Class 'Mageplaza\Core\Helper\AbstractData' not found

Tags: abstract-class

> Fatal error: Class 'Mageplaza\Core\Helper\AbstractData' not found in
>   /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Mageplaza/SocialLogin/Helper/Data.php
>   on line 32

Facing this issue after run upgrade command in Magento 2

Comment: Have you installed Mageplaza Core module?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Mageplaza core module also. Please open below link:
https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh